# Using a python dictionary to count a frequency and calculate a mean

Tags: python, dictionary, mean

I am looking ways to make my code more readable. I am reading info from a list of dictionaries that contains different phrases in different languages and a value associated to the phrase. I would like to calculate the average value of the score per language. I would like to create a new dictionary where the keys would be the languages and the values the average of the score per language.

Example:

**Input:**

```
d1={language:fr, score:2}
d2={language:de, score:5}
d3={language:de, score:7}
d4={language:fr, score:8}
list=[d1,d2,d3,d4]
```

**Output would be:**

```
d5={fr:5, de:6}
```

Until now i have first iterated over the list, creating a dictionary where the key is the language and the value a tuple with the sum of the score and how many times we have seen this particular language.

Then I have reiterated over the same dictionary dividing the first element of the tuple (the sum of scores) with the second element (how many times we have seen scores in this language) to calculate the mean.

I suppose there should be a better option to calculate mean.

```
new_d={defaultdict(lambda[0.0,0.0])}


for dictionary in list:
    new_d[dictionary[language]][0]+=dictionary[score]
    new_d[dictionary[language]][1]+=1
for key in new_d:
    new_d[key]=new_d[key][0]/new_d[key][1]
print(new_d)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe ask on [codereview.se]. However, you should post real code, not this fake code. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: This could probably be done in one-liners using the `collections` module or numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, which is more readable than the other answer:

```py
from statistics import mean


d1={'language':'fr', 'score':2}
d2={'language':'de', 'score':5}
d3={'language':'de', 'score':7}
d4={'language':'fr', 'score':8}

list1=[d1,d2,d3,d4]

languages = set(element['language'] for element in list1)
out = {}
for language in languages:
    out[language] = mean(element['score'] for element in list1 if element['language'] == language)

print(out)
>>> {'de': 6, 'fr': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option to calculate mean is using [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean). Here in my example I combine it with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to calculate the output dictionary (one-liner):

```
from statistics import mean
from itertools import groupby

d1={'language':'fr', 'score':2}
d2={'language':'de', 'score':5}
d3={'language':'de', 'score':7}
d4={'language':'fr', 'score':8}
lst=[d1,d2,d3,d4]

out = {v: mean(i['score'] for i in g) for v, g in groupby(sorted(lst, key=lambda k: k['language']), key=lambda k: k['language'])}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'de': 6, 'fr': 5}
```

You can also use `pandas` or `numpy` module - It will be more effective with huge datasets.